# Need free service that stores files and provides legal proof of date of upload

Tags: website, services, timestamp, legal

I am compiling some documents on a proof of concept. I want to find an authority that could store a document and certify in the future that:

- I am the author of said document.
- The date at which the document was uploaded has not been tampered with.
- The document remained unchanged since.

Is there a website that can act as such an authority?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try some timestamping services online. They'll digitally sign a timestamp. You get both free and paid for services. To get you started, have a look at these:

- [timemarker](http://www.timemarker.org/en/)
- [Certum](http://www.certum.eu/certum/cert,offer_time_stamp.xml)
- [digistamp](http://www.digistamp.com/)
- [authentidate](http://www.authentidate.com/)
- or [proofspace](https://issuer.proofspace.com:8080/ProofMarkOnDemand/)

For more info, read the [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trusted_timestamping) article on the subject. You'll have to choose a service that answers to your needs. (that will depend on a lot of factors that only you will know)